# avoid using location while app is in the background

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I am using the google google places api or an iOS app and was wondering how to avoid having to ask for allowing "always on" location (NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription). I do not think my app needs to access the location while in the background (is there a reason to?)

My google places api call is in a callback in viewDidLoad. Should I put it elsewhere in order to only ask for less intrusive permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods on `CLLocationManager` that request the location access. In order to request location access while the app is running you need to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`.

For example:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

I'm assuming you were following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place) where it show location access like this:

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

That method does request the access to always use your device's location, even while the app is in the background.

Hope that helps!